# Postgresql won't return display query result from if statement

Tags: postgresql, function, if-statement

This is the query I ran, and successfully was able to execute. But postgresql only display "CREATE FUNCTION -- Query returned successfully in 265 msec."

```
-- For every order that has been received, display the order ID, the total dollar amount owed on that order
-- (you’ll have to calculate this total from attributes in one or more tables; label this result TotalDue), and 
-- the amount received in payments on that order (assume that there is only one payment made on each 
-- order). To make this query a little simpler, you don’t have to include those orders for which nopayment 
-- has yet been received. List the results in decreasing order of the difference between total due and amount paid.


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun() RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE result1 text;
BEGIN
    IF  (SELECT pay.paymentamount 
        FROM order_t o JOIN orderline_t ol ON o.orderid = ol.orderid
        LEFT JOIN payment_t pay ON pay.orderid = o.orderid
        JOIN product_t pr ON pr.productid = ol.productid
        WHERE orderedquantity > 0
        GROUP BY o.orderid, pay.paymentamount) != NULL
    THEN
        SELECT o.orderid, sum(ol.orderedquantity * pr.productstandardprice) AS total_due, pay.paymentamount, 
        sum(ol.orderedquantity * pr.productstandardprice) - paymentamount AS total_owed
        INTO result1
        FROM order_t o
        JOIN orderline_t ol ON o.orderid = ol.orderid
        LEFT JOIN payment_t pay ON pay.orderid = o.orderid
        JOIN product_t pr ON pr.productid = ol.productid
        WHERE orderedquantity > 0
        GROUP BY o.orderid, pay.paymentamount
        ORDER BY o.orderid;
    ELSE    
        SELECT o.orderid, sum(ol.orderedquantity * pr.productstandardprice) AS total_due, pay.paymentamount, 
        sum(ol.orderedquantity * pr.productstandardprice) AS total_owed
        INTO result1
        FROM order_t o
        JOIN orderline_t ol ON o.orderid = ol.orderid
        LEFT JOIN payment_t pay ON pay.orderid = o.orderid
        JOIN product_t pr ON pr.productid = ol.productid
        WHERE orderedquantity > 0
        GROUP BY o.orderid, pay.paymentamount
        ORDER BY o.orderid;
    END IF;
    RETURN result1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

For orders where a payment hasn't been logged in the payment_t table, I go ahead and set the total_owed to total_due.

Answer (score 0):

You have created your function, but you have not run it! The [PostgreSQL Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-calling-funcs.html) has numerous examples on how to call a function after running it. I am not that familiar with it, but it looks like you could simply run `SELECT fun()`

Comment: Thanks for responding. Executing SELECT fun(), returned the value of 1. If there's a less complicated/more novice alternative to not using function that would be appreciated as well.